# Store Json data using Sterling database in wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, nosql

How to save Json data using sterling database in wp8.1?

Any help would Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you http://www.devride.com/index.php/using-sterling-as-db-for-windows-phone-8/

Did you considered using SQLite? I think it's a better option for storing data. I was using JSON files but they can get corrupted very easy.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply.I checked above mentioned Link but unfortunatly that is not for store Json data.I know Sqlite Db but  as of my requirement I need to use Nosql Db only.

Comment: Ok ,I went through Lex.DB but I am not sure is it noSql Db or not.Please can you suggest about Lex.db?
Please have look on these 
1.http://lexblog.azurewebsites.net/intro-to-lex-db/                                                                2.http://wp.qmatteoq.com/lex-db-a-new-database-storage-solution-for-windows-phone-8/